# Two dimensional grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

is it possible with basic ASP.net controls or Telerik's RadControls to get a two dimensional grid ?
I can't find informations so far ...
thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you can't find one, why won't you make one? What is your need frmo the two dimensional grid? How is it different from a data grid view?

Comment: What is your actual requirement??

Comment: Something like this for instance : http://lemondedesetudes.fr/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Tableau_2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two dimensional grid would be a [HTML Table](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp).

With ASP.NET you can use a [GridView](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/gridview-example-how-to-use-gridview-in.html) control.

With Telerik controls, you could use a [Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) control.

It depends what you need the two dimensional grid for.

Answer (score 0):

"A two dimensional grid" is a very vague requirement, but depending on what your data source is the [System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control is very powerful.

Comment: Something like this for instance is possible?:
http://lemondedesetudes.fr/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Tableau_2.png

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the `GridView` control is for